String interpolation inside PodTemplate in Jenkinsfile
I am trying to add the value of image_tag and region inside podtemplate but its not working.
Error failed to add image information to the policy rule context: invalid image 'aws-cli:${image_version}' (bad image: docker.io/aws-cli:${image_version}, defaultRegistry: docker.io, enableDefaultRegistryMutation: true: invalid reference format)
I am using this plugin https://plugins.jenkins.io/kubernetes/
image_version = '2.15.40'
region = 'us-east-1'
podTemplate(yaml: '''
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Pod
    metadata:
      labels:
        label: label
    spec:
     containers:
     - name: aws-cli:${image_version}
       image: 
       env:
       - name: AWS_REGION
         value: ${region}
       resources:
         requests:
           cpu: "2"
           memory: "3Gi"
         limits:
           cpu: "2"
           memory: "3Gi"
       alwaysPullImage: true
       tty: true
       securityContext:
         privileged: true
''')


You are using triple single quoted string ''', which don't do variable interpolation. You need to use triple double quoted strings """ instead. See groovy docs.

Groovy script allows string interpolation only inside double quotations (“). It will take the content as text without any variable evaluation if you are using single quotation (‘) for the script. In your case you need to use three double quotations(“””) to interpolate variables. At the same time you need to use a single quotation(‘) for the resource request block. Take a look into the example below to understand correctly.
podTemplate(yaml: """
apiVersion: v1 
kind: Pod 
metadata: 
  labels: 
    label: label 
spec: 
 containers:
   - name: aws-cli-container
     image: aws-cli:${image_version}
     env: 
       - name: AWS_REGION 
         value: ${region} 
     resources: 
       requests: 
         cpu: '2' 
         memory: '3Gi' 
       limits: 
         cpu: '2' 
         memory: '3Gi' 
     alwaysPullImage: true 
     tty: true 
     securityContext: 
       privileged: true  
""")


Check this document for more detailed information about Groovy variable interpolation.
